# Azure Function queue items processing

Tags: c#, azure

I’m new to Azure and I’m trying to figure out solution for following problem:

- Application push items to queue
- ‘Worker‘ pick items from queue and    process it(processing time is
  around 10-20sec)

Idea for solution is:

- WebApp enqueue items using Service Buss Queue
- Azure Function(AF) use ServiceBusTrigger to pick items from queue

But I’m not sure how it would behaves. My concerns are:

- Let say AF is ‘down‘ for some time. When it ‘gets up’ and queue isn’t
  empty then will it be triggered? Or trigger will only work when new
  item is added to the queue?
- When AF job is done will it be triggered again if there are more items in the queue?
- Do I have to manage how many AF workers will be available? Can one instance of AF process multiple queue items at same time? In ideal scenario all items should be processed immediately after they are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When it is available it will pick up items in the queue, at least that's the behaviour for storage queue
2. Yes
3. No, you dont have to, and in ideal world Azure Function would scale to process any number of items, but that is not always the case. You might want to use batching if your Azure Functions are incapable of handling the load